# Filter results by users contained in a Users Relations RelatedTo field

Tags: templating, users, relations, relatedto

I would like to exclude entries from appearing in the template results that contain Users from specific User group.

My code below works if **all** the User(s) in the RelatedTo field are part of the excluded User group, but it doesn't work if the field contains Users from both the excluded group and a non-excluded group.

```
{% set excludeFellows = craft.users.groupId('not 11') %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('logsQA').logGeneral_statusWorkflow('submitted').relatedTo(
    { targetElement: excludeFellows, field: 'logGeneral_sonographerName' }
) %}
```

(Also if it's better to check for specific User IDs rather than a User Group for my excluded list that's fine too. I only have 3 Users to exclude.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to exclude any entry that has any user from a certain user group selected in a certain Users field.

Here's an approach that I believe would work:

```
{# Get the users that should be excluded #}
{% set excludedUsers = craft.users.group('groupToExclude').limit(null) %}

{# Get the entries that should be excluded #}
{% set excludedEntries = craft.entries.section('logsQA').relatedTo({
    targetElement: excludedUsers.ids(),
    field: 'logGeneral_sonographerName'
}).limit(null) %}

{# Get the entries that should be displayed #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('logsQA').id('and, not '~excludedEntries.ids()|join(', not ')) %}
```

What the above does is to first pull the users that should be excluded (you could use the `groupId` parameter instead of `group` if you want to), before using those users to pull the entries that should be excluded.

Finally, the entries that should be displayed are pulled – the key here is the use of the `id` parameter to specifically exclude a list of entry IDs.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thanks @Mats.  One thing I missed at first was to replace the "groupToExclude" in the first set variable with the group name.  Just pointing it out in case anyone else misses that too.

Comment: Awesome! Right, "groupToExclude" is just a placeholder, and should be replaced with the real handle for the group you want to exclude.